# sed ' in replacement text when $ in search pattern

Tags: bash, sed, zsh

I have a file containing the string "this $c$ is a single quote", created as follows:

```
 %echo "this \$c\$ is a single quote" > test3.txt
 %cat test3.txt
this $c$ is a single quote
```

I would like to replace the letter c by a single quote, but I need to match the $ characters as well (to avoid matching other characters 'c').  I can't seem to do this.

I tried

```
 %sed 's/$c$/$foo$/' test3.txt
this $c$ is a single quote
```

so obviously I need to escape the $.

```
 %sed 's/\$c\$/$foo$/' test3.txt
this $foo$ is a single quote
```

But when I try to put an escaped ' in the replacement text I get

```
 %sed 's/$c$/$\'$/' test3.txt
quote>
```

So I need to use some other quoting method.

```
 %sed "s/\$c\$/$'$/" test3.txt
this $c$ is a single quote
```

Nothing was replaced, so let's try not escaping the $

```
 %sed "s/$c$/$'$/" test3.txt
this $c$ is a single quote$'$
```

That was unexpected (to me), so let's try matching just the `c` as a sanity check.

```
 %sed "s/c/'/" test3.txt
this $'$ is a single quote
```

I tried a number of other combinations but no luck.  How do I do this in `sed`?

Comment: This might be a good interview question :D

Comment: Why don't you read the manual / some article about quotes? You're wasting a lot of time with this guess-work.

Comment: which manual?  sed or bash?  The answers below are quite useful, in any case.

Comment: Your shell. the `zsh` tag doesn't really help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
!$ echo 'This is $c$ ceee' | sed s/\\\$c\\\$/\'/
This is ' ceee
```

I do not enclose the whole sed's command in quotes, so I need to escape each backslash and each dollar separately (and the quote as well, of course).

**Edit**
As Chris Lear points out, my replace string contains no dollars. Here is a fix – please note *these* dollars do not have a special meaning for `sed` (they are not interpreted as symbols for match, they're just plain characters to be inserted) so they can be escaped only once:

```
!$ echo 'This is $c$ ceee' | sed s/\\\$c\\\$/\\\$\'\\\$/
This is $'$ ceee

!$ echo 'This is $c$ ceee' | sed s/\\\$c\\\$/\$\'\$/
This is $'$ ceee
```

Comment: Or `sed 's/\$c\$/$'\''$/' test3.txt`

Comment: Note that the replacement in this answer doesn't include the `$` characters, but they can be added as per the other answer which is similar.

Comment: I don't understand why @ChrisLear's suggestion works (it does), as it looks like you are just closing the sed command prematurely.

Comment: @ChrisLear  Right. Added. Thank you.

Comment: @Alejandro, bash does not allow you to embed a single quote inside a single quoted string. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting . Chris's suggesting concatenates 3 separate strings to compose the sed body: `'s/\$c\$/$'`, a literal single quote, and then `'$/'`

Comment: @Alejandro Chris's version is a concatenation of three strings: quoted `s/\$c\$/$`, an escaped quote alone `\'` and quoted `$/`, making `s/\$c\$/$'$/` as a resulting parameter to `sed`.

Comment: I see.  So these are concatenated in the shell before passed to sed, rather than being passed to sed as different commands or something.

Comment: Yes, bash performs a [series of defined expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) before the command is launched. Handling quoted strings is one of them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to quote the `sed` command you need to do plenty of escaping.  `$` is a special character for both the shell and the `sed` patterns.  In the shell it means the start of a variable name to expand, `$c` in your case.  To `sed` it means the end of the line.  To do the quoting you need to escape it from both of those so you could do

```
 sed "s/\\\$c\\\$/\$'\$/" test3.txt
```

or you could mix your quoting styles to use single quotes around the $ expansions and double quotes around your single quote like

```
sed 's/\$c\$/$'"'"'$/' test3.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ansi c string

```
sed $'s/\$c\$/\'/'
```

This allows single backslash escaping of `$`s and `'`s.

[More info here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

If you want to keep `$`s

```
sed $'s/\$c\$/$\'$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed -i -E "s/([$]c[$])/\'/g" sed.txt
```